# Quarkus generated project fails on GraalVM 19.3 and JDK11

Tags: quarkus

I would like to run simple project generated from quarkus webpage and I am trying to run it on Linux with 19.3 GraalVM and JDK11. I know that the development of JDK11 support is still ongoing, but what version of GraalVM should I use then to test quarkus?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For Quarkus 1.0.x, you need to use GraalVM 19.2.1. You can download it from here: https://github.com/oracle/graal/releases/tag/vm-19.2.1 .

At the moment, we are working on two different fronts:

- GraalVM 19.3 support. It's mostly working but we still have a number of critical issues due to GraalVM bugs and I'm not sure if we will ship with it or not. 1.1.0.CR1 is using 19.3 but I'm still not sure about the Final tbh.
- GraalVM 19.3 + JDK 11 support: keep in mind that this is still preview on the GraalVM side. We are making slow progress on this as it comes with a new set of challenges. You can follow the progress here: https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues?q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen+label%3A%22GraalVM+%2B+Java+11%22 . We already made significant progress but as you can see we still have some issues to fix - some of them in Quarkus, some of them in GraalVM. Current planning is to have that one for January release (Quarkus 1.2).

Comment: Learned about quarkus from Software Engineering daily podcast, you are doing great work there. Thanks.